# How to structure teams, projects and specialties in JIRA

Tags: jira, agile, jira-agile, agile-project-management

We have a department team section in JIRA setup as a project and I have been asked to create Kanban boards and set the section up ready to use but I'm not sure the best way to apply the work the department team is managing into JIRA.

We want to have Kanban boards for two different specialties and for e.g. one of the specialties we have two projects and one of the projects has a subproject and also one of the projects may sometimes overlap with both specialties.

For example:

```
Build team
    Development Kanban Board
        Project A
            Project Sub Project/Stream A
            Project Sub Project/Stream B
        Project B
    Test Kanban Board
        Project A
```

My current thoughts are:

- Project = Team
- Component = Project A
- Epic = Project Sub
  Project/Stream
- Labels = Specialty Kanban Board

Is the above correct or is there another approach that would be best practice for this scenario?  At the moment I think we are tied into having the Project in JIRA set as the team

Comment: How big are your projects? Are they just a few days long, or several weeks?

Answer (score -1):

Usual practice is to make your projects correspond to JIRA projects (thus the name). You can set up the filters for Kanban boards to bring in issues from multiple projects according to whatever criteria you want. This will make it easier if issues need to flow from the dev team to the test team. The "Team" can be defined by assignee, status, or another field if you prefer. Epics are good for time-bounded subprojects, components are good for ongoing subelements (e.g. UI, database, etc.).